# SQL- Find all students who all of their friends have score less than 10

Tags: sql-server, group-by, where-in

I have to write some simple queries for my database homework using **SQLServer**. The schema has been provided in the question:

```
students(student_id, name);
friends(student_id, friend_id);
db_grades(student_id, grade);
```

For every pair of friends, 2 rows like `(x, y)` and `(y, x)` would be added to the `friends` table

> Find all students, who all of their friends have a score of less than
> 10

First I tried to solve this question using `GROUP BY`, and I wrote the below query.

```
Select Distinct s.name, MAX(g.grade)
       From (students s inner join friends f on s.student_id = f.student_id), db_grades g
       Where f.friend_id = g.student_id
       Group by f.friend_id, s.name
       Having MAX(g.grade) < 10;
```

And in the second try, I wanted to implement it using the `IN` keyword, but it also does not work correctly.

```
Select distinct s.name
    From students s  join friends f on s.student_id = f.student_id
    Where f.friend_id not in
    (
       Select f.friend_id
       From  db_grades g1
       Where g1.student_id = f.friend_id and g1.grade > 10
    )
```

I will be grateful for your help on how to write the correct query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation is one option:

```sql
SELECT s.student_id, s.name
FROM students s
INNER JOIN friends f
    ON f.student_id = s.student_id
INNER JOIN db_grades g
    ON g.student_id = f.friend_id
GROUP BY s.student_id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN f.grade >= 10 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have just edited my question, I have forgotten to add some more information about the `friends` table. I think with this extra condition your query will not work correctly. Thanks.

Comment: My answer doesn't need to change actually.  The `HAVING` clause immediately fails upon detecting any grade >= 10.

Comment: Does it check it for both of the columns of the `friends` table? for example, if a student with `id` = 16 befriends a student with `id` = 18, and the score of the student with `id`= 16 is more than 10 then the student with `id` = 18, must not be returned.

Comment: The join to the `db_grades` table is one way.  That the data is duplicated in both directions does not matter.

Comment: Yes, may you please explain how does the `CASE...WHEN` work in the `COUNT` function? and why did you write 1 after `THEN`? thanks again.

Comment: The `COUNT(CASE ...)` expression _counts_ the number of times there is a grade equal to or greater than 10.  Your requirement is that a matching student's friends should all have grades < 10, so this count expression should be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `NOT EXISTS`. Note that the difference between this and `HAVING` with an `INNER JOIN` is that this option includes those that have no friends at all.

```sql
SELECT s.student_id, s.name
FROM students s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM friends f
    INNER JOIN db_grades g
        ON g.student_id = f.friend_id
    WHERE f.student_id = s.student_id
      AND g.grade >= 10
);
```